# qdatawidgetmapper for displaying qicons?

Tags: qt, qicon

I'm currently trying to create a widget which allows me to display properties of a given tool. I have a model containing all tools, and what i would like to create is basically a combobox which allows to select one tool and the tools properties are then displayed using icons.

my model already has defined different roles e.g. decoration and display role, but i'm wondering how to build a widget which only reacts on the decoration role of the model.

thanks a lot in advance
donny

Answer (score 0):

Try a `QLabel`

Specifically mapping its `pixmap` property:

```
myMapper.addMapping(myLabel, itsSection, "pixmap")
```